# With NR==FNR, need to modify the two files when there is a match

Tags: text-processing, awk

When a line of the b.txt file is matched, I would like to modify the a.txt line in entrance (ie replace $1 by $2 of the b.txt file) but it doesn't work.

**Inputs**

```
*a.txt*
201 A B 580 D1
208 A B 581 D2
214 A B 582 D3

*b.txt*
10 101 E1 A Z1 B Z2 580 Z3
11 104 E2 C Z1 B Z2 581 Z3
12 107 E3 A Z1 B Z2 581 Z3
14 111 E3 B Z1 S Z2 582 Z3
15 116 E2 A Z1 B Z2 582 Z3
```

**Outputs**

```
*c.txt*
101 A B 580 D1
107 A B 581 D2
116 A B 582 D3
10 101 E1 A Z1 B Z2 580 Z3
12 107 E3 A Z1 B Z2 581 Z3
15 116 E2 A Z1 B Z2 582 Z3
```

**MyCode**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{pattern[$0]; next} {if($4" "$6" "$8 in pattern) {print $0; gsub(pattern[$1],$2); print pattern[$0]}}' a.txt b.txt >> c.txt
```

What's wrong with my code, I have no result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to revised question:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {$1=""; afile[$2, $3, $4]=$0; next; }
    (($4, $6, $8) in afile){ print $2 afile[$4, $6, $8]; }1' a.txt b.txt
```

---

Valid for old revision of the question:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR { afile[$2, $3, $4]=1; next; } 
       (($4, $6, $8) in afile){ print $2, $4 ,$6 , $8; }1' a.txt b.txt >c.txt
```

read the `a.txt` only columns 2, 3 and 4 into an associated array called `afile`; then compare on corresponding columns on the second file `b.txt` on 4, 6 and 8, if there were seen in the array so print the desired columns from the second file `$1` intact and rest of the columns 4, 6 and 8 as well; else print by default `1` for unmatched lines.

Result `c.txt`:

```
101 A B 580
10 101 E1 A Z1 B Z2 580 Z3
11 104 E2 C Z1 B Z2 581 Z3
107 A B 581
12 107 E3 A Z1 B Z2 581 Z3
14 111 E3 B Z1 S Z2 582 Z3
116 A B 582
15 116 E2 A Z1 B Z2 582 Z3
```

---

But your codes issues:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{pattern[$0]; next} {if($4" "$6" "$8 in pattern) {print $0; gsub(pattern[$1],$2); print pattern[$0]}}' a.txt b.txt >> c.txt
```

1. `pattern[$0]`: with this you add each entire line into the *pattern* associated array from the first input "`a.txt`";
2. next you compare columns #4, #6 and #8 with `$4" "$6" "$8` from the second file `b.txt` on against the lines in that array; these will never match, since you are comparing entire lines with specific columns values that do not exist in your *pattern* array.
3. since step 2 never meet your inner block for if statement also never run; and I'm not going to explain that what you are doing with that.

Answer (score 0):

First we construct a regex of 8 chunks/fields with remembering the even number of fields. The regex is based on gnu sed with extended regexp mode.

```
$ re='\S+ (\S+)'
$ for i in 1 2; do re="$re $re"; done
$ sed -En "/\n/{P;d;}
    s/\s+/ /g;s/^ | \$//g
    /(\S+ ){6}/bb
    s/^\S+ //;H;d
    :b;G
    /^$re .*\n(\2 \3 \4 \S+)/{
      s//\1 \5\n&/;P;D
    }
" a.txt b.txt \
| sed -e 'n;H;2h;$!d;g'
```

**Output:**

```
101 A B 580 D1
107 A B 581 D2
116 A B 582 D3
10 101 E1 A Z1 B Z2 580 Z3
12 107 E3 A Z1 B Z2 581 Z3
15 116 E2 A Z1 B Z2 582 Z3
```

Comment: Why would you use something like that when an awk script to do the same is so clear, simple, portable, etc.?